# FastAPI handling and redirecting 404

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, fastapi

How can i redirect a request with FastAPI if there is a HTTPException?

In Flask we can achieve that like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_404(e):
    if request.path.startswith('/api'):
        return render_template('my_api_404.html'), 404
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Or in Django we can use django.shortcuts:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def view_404(request, exception=None):
    return redirect('/')
```

How we can achieve that with FastAPI?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know it's too late but this is the shortest approach to handle 404 exceptions in your personal way.

**Redirect**

```
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse


@app.exception_handler(404)
async def custom_404_handler(_, __):
    return RedirectResponse("/")
```

**Custom Jinja Template**

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.exception_handler(404)
async def custom_404_handler(request, __):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("404.html", {"request": request})
```

**Serve HTML from file**

```
@app.exception_handler(404)
async def custom_404_handler(_, __):
    return FileResponse('./path/to/404.html')
```

**Serve HTML directly**

```
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

response_404 = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The file you requested was not found.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
    
@app.exception_handler(404)
async def custom_404_handler(_, __):
    return HTMLResponse(response_404)
```

**Note**: `exception_handler` decorator passes the current `request` and `exception` as arguments to the function. I've used `_` and `__` where the variables are unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

We can achieve that by using FastAPI's **exception_handler**:

If you are in a hurry, you can use this:

```
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def custom_http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return RedirectResponse("/")
```

But more spesific approach, you can create your own Exception Handler(s):

```
class UberSuperHandler(StarletteHTTPException):
    pass
    
def function_for_uber_super_handler(request, exc):
    return RedirectResponse("/")


app.add_exception_handler(UberSuperHandler, function_for_uber_super_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I uses this method,

```py
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
async def custom_http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("404.html", {"request": request})
```

- Make sure you have static folder, for your static files and templates folder your html files.